# Running custom setuptools build during install

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I've tried to implement Compass compiling during setuptools' `build`, but the following code runs compilation during explicit `build` command and doesn't runs during `install`.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import setuptools
from distutils.command.build import build


SETUP_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


class BuildCSS(setuptools.Command):
    description = 'build CSS from SCSS'

    user_options = []

    def initialize_options(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        os.chdir(os.path.join(SETUP_DIR, 'django_project_dir', 'compass_project_dir'))
        import platform
        if 'Windows' == platform.system():
            command = 'compass.bat compile'
        else:
            command = 'compass compile'
        import subprocess
        try:
            subprocess.check_call(command.split())
        except (subprocess.CalledProcessError, OSError):
            print 'ERROR: problems with compiling Sass. Is Compass installed?'
            raise SystemExit
        os.chdir(SETUP_DIR)

    def finalize_options(self):
        pass


class Build(build):
    sub_commands = build.sub_commands + [('build_css', None)]


setuptools.setup(
    # Custom attrs here.
    cmdclass={
        'build': Build,
        'build_css': BuildCSS,
    },
)
```

Any custom instructions at `Build.run` (e.g. some printing) doesn't apply during `install` too, but `dist` instance contains in `commands` attribute only my `build` command implementation instances. Incredible! But I think the trouble is in complex relations between `setuptools` and `distutils`. Does anybody knows how to make custom building run during `install` on Python 2.7?

**Update:** Found that `install` definitely doesn't calls `build` command, but it calls `bdist_egg` which runs `build_ext`. Seems like I should implement "Compass" build extension.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunatelly, I haven't found the answer. Seems like the ability to run post-install scripts correctly there's [only at Distutils 2.](http://www.mail-archive.com/distutils-sig@python.org/msg02288.html) Now you can use this work-around:

**Update:** Because of setuptools' stack checks, we should override `install.do_egg_install`, not `run` method:

```python
from setuptools.command.install import install

class Install(install):
    def do_egg_install(self):
        self.run_command('build_css')
        install.do_egg_install(self)
```

**Update2:** `easy_install` runs exactly `bdist_egg` command which is used by `install` too, so the most correct way (espetially if you want to make `easy_install` work) is to override `bdist_egg` command. Whole code:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import setuptools
from distutils.command.build import build as _build
from setuptools.command.bdist_egg import bdist_egg as _bdist_egg


class bdist_egg(_bdist_egg):
    def run(self):
        self.run_command('build_css')
        _bdist_egg.run(self)


class build_css(setuptools.Command):
    description = 'build CSS from SCSS'

    user_options = []

    def initialize_options(self):
        pass

    def finalize_options(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        pass # Here goes CSS compilation.


class build(_build):
    sub_commands = _build.sub_commands + [('build_css', None)]


setuptools.setup(

    # Here your setup args.

    cmdclass={
        'bdist_egg': bdist_egg,
        'build': build,
        'build_css': build_css,
    },
)
```

You may see how I've used this [here.](https://github.com/quasiyoke/keys_of_peace/blob/master/setup.py)