# python setuptools install_requires is ignored when overriding cmdclass

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, install-requires

I have a `setup.py` that looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup
from subprocess import call
from setuptools.command.install import install

class MyInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        call(["pip install -r requirements.txt --no-clean"], shell=True)
        install.run(self)

setup(
    author='Attila Zseder',
    version='0.1',
    name='entity_extractor',
    packages=['...'],
    install_requires=['DAWG', 'mrjob', 'cchardet'],
    package_dir={'': 'modules'},
    scripts=['...'],
    cmdclass={'install': MyInstall},
)
```

I need `MyInstall` because I want to install some libraries from github and I didn't want to use `dependency_links` option, because it's discouraged (for example [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pypa-dev/tJ6HHPQpyJ4)), so I can do this with requirements.txt.

When I install this package with `pip`, everything is working fine, but for some reasons I have to solve this in a way that it also works with pure `python setup.py install`. And it doesn't.

When overriding `cmdclass` in `setup()` with my own class, `install_requires` seems to be ignored. As soon as I comment out that line, those packages are being installed.

I know that install_requires is not supported for example in distutils (if I remember well), but it is in setuptools. And then `cmdclass` wouldn't have any effect on `install_requires`.

I googled this problem for hours, found a lot of kind of related answers on stackoverflow, but not for this particular problem.

With putting every needed package to requirements.txt, everything's working fine, but I would like to understand why this is happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The same problem just happened to me. It somehow seems like something triggers setuptools to do an 'old-style install' with `distutils`, which indeed does not support `install_requires`.

You call install.run(self) which calls run(self) in setuptools/setuptools/command/install.py, line 51-74

https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/src/8e8c50925f18eafb7e66fe020aa91a85b9a4b122/setuptools/command/install.py?at=default

```
def run(self):
    # Explicit request for old-style install?  Just do it
    if self.old_and_unmanageable or self.single_version_externally_managed:
        return _install.run(self)

    # Attempt to detect whether we were called from setup() or by another
    # command.  If we were called by setup(), our caller will be the
    # 'run_command' method in 'distutils.dist', and *its* caller will be
    # the 'run_commands' method.  If we were called any other way, our
    # immediate caller *might* be 'run_command', but it won't have been
    # called by 'run_commands'.  This is slightly kludgy, but seems to
    # work.
    #
    caller = sys._getframe(2)
    caller_module = caller.f_globals.get('__name__','')
    caller_name = caller.f_code.co_name

    if caller_module != 'distutils.dist' or caller_name!='run_commands':
        # We weren't called from the command line or setup(), so we
        # should run in backward-compatibility mode to support bdist_*
        # commands.
        _install.run(self)
    else:
        self.do_egg_install()
```

I'm not sure whether this behaviour is intended, but replacing

```
install.run(self)
```

with

```
install.do_egg_install()
```

should solve your problem. At least it works for me, but I would also appreciate a more detailed answer. Thanks!

Comment: It did solve my problem, thank you! But yes, I would also appreciate a detailed answer about the reasons.

Comment: Interesting observation for anyone wondering: As explained [here](http://www.niteoweb.com/blog/setuptools-run-custom-code-during-install), `setuptools` commands subclass [`distutils.cmd.Command`](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/python-distutils/src/48c42eeaee4410d76675b637bcd401b8919ff19a/cmd.py?at=default#cl-14), which is an old-style Python `class`. For this reason, `super` cannot be used, and the parent class has to be referenced directly.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `install.do_egg_install(self)`?

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer more than once. Also, when using python3, calling `super().do_egg_install()` worked fine

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, I think so. I pasted the code and faced a syntax error I ever met long back to the days I started learning python.

Comment: @dusktreader your python3 fix doesn't seem to work for python 3.6.0.

Comment: Using this solution I got `ERROR: Failed building wheel` messages when installing my package from PyPi. My conclusion is that `cmdclass` should not be relied on for production modules. It's too poorly documented and has too many edge cases where things unexpectedly fail.

Comment: this does not work for python 3.6; it creates the egg folder under the wheel folder while it is expected to be under `build/bdist.linux-x86_64/`

Answer (score 12):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/20196065 a more correct way to do this may be to override `bdist_egg` command.

You could try:

```
from setuptools.command.bdist_egg import bdist_egg as _bdist_egg

class bdist_egg(_bdist_egg):
    def run(self):
        call(["pip install -r requirements.txt --no-clean"], shell=True)
        _bdist_egg.run(self)

...

setup(...
    cmdclass={'bdist_egg': bdist_egg},  # override bdist_egg
)
```

It worked for me and `install_require`is no more ignored. Nevertheless, I still don't understand why most people seem to override `cmdclass install` and do not complain about `install_require` being ignored.

Comment: Perhaps they are only using `pip install` and never `python setup.py install`, or when using the latter they do so in a `virtualenv` already populated with dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I ran into a similar problem. The solution I have found fixes this problem for me is very subtle: The `install` class you're setting in `cmd_class` must *physically be named* `install`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806485/execute-a-python-script-post-install-using-distutils-setuptools#18159969) on a related issue.

> Note that I use the class name install for my derived class because that is what python setup.py --help-commands will use.

You also should use `self.execute(_func_name, (), msg="msg")` in your post_install instead of calling the function directly

So implementing something like this should cause you to avoid the `do_egg_install` workaround implemented above by KEgg.

```
from setuptools.command.install import install as _install
...
def _post_install():
    #code here
class install(_install):
    def run(self):
        _install.run(self)
        self.execute(_post_install, (), msg="message here")
```

Comment: Are you sure with that? I can't reproduce and that also doesn't solve the frame check in setuptools' `run` implementation.

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure. `setuptools` is very underdocumented, and often behaves sporadically. I was able to get the desired behavior for my PyPI package with reproducible post-install commands, perhaps in ways I don't understand. You can download, unzip, and then examine the setup.py for yourself:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/arcgis