# Installing nltk data dependencies in setup.py script

Tags: python, nltk, setup.py, wordnet, python-packaging

I use NLTK with wordnet in my project. I did the installation manually on my PC, with pip:
`pip3 install nltk --user` in a terminal, then `nltk.download()` in a python shell to download wordnet.

I want to automatize these with a `setup.py` file, but I don't know a good way to install wordnet.

For the moment, I have this piece of code after the call to `setup` (`"nltk"` is in the `install_requires` list of the call to `setup`):

```
import sys
if 'install' in sys.argv:
    import nltk
    nltk.download("wordnet")
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @martin-thoma from a quick glance, looks like the _nltk data_ dependencies could be packaged as Python projects and distributed on PyPI without too much work. The whole thing could be relatively easily scripted and delegated to a CI/CD system. You should weigh in on these tickets: https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/issues/12 https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/2228

Comment: @martin-thoma also, here is a rather similar post I wrote about the same problem with spacy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57773454/package-spacy-model/57782864#57782864 does that apply to your situation as well?

Comment: For my use case, the best option seemed to be to list all dependencies in a `requirements.txt` file and use `pip install -r requirements.txt` first. Then in my `setup.py` I have the manual download command `nltk.download("punkt")` which is used when I run `pip install -e .` I believe this works because I'm building a Docker image/container, not trying to distribute a package.

Answer (score 14):

I managed to install the NLTK data in setup.py by overriding `cmdclass` with my own `Install` class :

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools.command.install import install as _install


class Install(_install):
    def run(self):
        _install.do_egg_install(self)
        import nltk
        nltk.download("popular")

setup(...
    cmdclass={'install': Install},
    ...
    install_requires=[
      'nltk',
      ],
    setup_requires=['nltk']
    ...
   )
```

It is important to use the method `do_egg_install()` in your `run()` method to make sure nltk gets installed, before `import nltk` is called (See also here [python setuptools install_requires is ignored when overriding cmdclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915469/python-setuptools-install-requires-is-ignored-when-overriding-cmdclass)). Also don't forget to add `nltk` to `setup_requires`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me!

Comment: Also did not work for me

Comment: Also did not work for me

Answer (score 3):

You can also automate installation with a shell script, for example, running (after pip installing nltk):

```
python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/share/nltk_data wordnet
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37553710/13180500), external data should not be handled by setuptools in setup.py. As an alternative I suggest that in the `__init__.py` file of your package you include the following lines (putting the case that you want to download the `punkt` and `stopwords`) :

```py
__version__ = "x.x.x"
__organization__ = "your_organization"  
import nltk 
nltk.download("stopwords") 
nltk.download("punkt")
```

This way the files will not be downloaded when the package is installed, but when it is imported (i.e. `import my_package`).

---

As an **example** I share a [link](https://github.com/Huertas97/pyleetspeak/blob/main/pyleetspeak/__init__.py) to a python library that does just this.

First you would have to install the library:

```bash
pip install -U pyleetspeak
```

And then importing the library will download the NLTK files:

```py
import pyleetspeak
pyleetspeak.__version__
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This setup worked for me:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools.command.install import install

class InstallCommand(install):
    def run(self):
        install.run(self)
        import nltk
        nltk.download('wordnet')

setup(
    # other options...

    install_requires=['nltk'],
    setup_requires=['nltk'],
    cmdclass={
        'install': InstallCommand,
    }
)
```