# Package spacy model

Tags: python, spacy, python-packaging

I want to include the spacy model de_core_news_sm in a python package.

Here is my project: https://github.com/michaelhochleitner/package_de_core_news_sm .

I package and install the project with the following commands.

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
pip install dist/example-pkg-mh-0.0.1.tar.gz
```

I want to import the module example_pkg.import-model.py .

```
$ python
>>> import example_pkg.import_model
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mh/PycharmProjects/packaging_tutorial/example_pkg/import_model.py", line 2, in <module>
    import de_core_news_sm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'de_core_news_sm'
```

How can I include the module 'de_core_news_sm' into the package so that it's installed after running the following command?

```
pip install dist/example-pkg-mh-0.0.1.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to spare your users from running that download, you'll have to package and distribute it with your own source. This process is called vendoring (see [this great post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52538252/import-vendored-dependencies-in-python-package-without-modifying-sys-path-or-3rd) for an in-depth explanation of how to best do it in python, or the pip-project's [`_vendor/__init__.py`](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/e4936da2e1b62c33f0ed9034f5c984ae17e38e86/src/pip/_vendor/__init__.py) for a commented example), and it can be quite convenient, but prone to get you into annoying issues if overdone.

Simply put, you create an additional python package called `_vendor` (or something similar) in the source code directory of your package and copy the downloaded `de_core_news_sm` package into it:

```
example_pkg
├── import_model.py
├── __init__.py
└── _vendor
    ├── __init__.py
    └── de_core_news_sm
        ├── de_core_news_sm-2.1.0
        │   ├── accuracy.json
        │   ├── meta.json
        │   ├── ner/
        │   ├── parser/
        │   ├── tagger/
        │   ├── vocab/
        │   └── tokenizer
        ├── __init__.py
        └── meta.json
```

You can find the package in the `site_packages` of the python interpreter that you installed it into with `python -m spacy download de_core_news_sm`, i.e. `$(which python)/site_packages/de_core_news_sm`.

Finally, you need to change all your imports of the model from `import de_core_news_sm` to `from example_pkg._vendor import de_core_news_sm`, and then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try on command line:

```
python -m spacy download de_core_news_sm
```

Comment: Yes. I want to spare the users of the package doing this manually.