# spacy models import issue in python package

Tags: python, pip, spacy, python-packaging

I am building a python package and in my main py file, I import Spacy language model like this. If it exist, it will be loaded otherwise it will be downloaded using shell command.

```
try:
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
except OSError:
    print("Downloading language model for the spaCy POS tagger do not worry, this will only happen once")
    os.system('python -m spacy download en_core_web_md')
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
```

When I install package, it downloads the model but gives error while importing.

```
You can now load the model via spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/shahid/Documents/simple_nlp/NlpFactory/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from NlpFactory.NlpFactory import NLPFactory
  File "/home/shahid/Documents/simple_nlp/NlpFactory/NlpFactory.py", line 28, in <module>
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
  File "/home/shahid/anaconda3/envs/eda_test_7/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 30, in load
    return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
  File "/home/shahid/anaconda3/envs/eda_test_7/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 175, in load_model
    raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_md'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

So I thought this is a path issue so I tried importing it like this.

```
nlp = spacy.load(os.path.abspath('en_core_web_md'))
```

It gave me this error which is quite similar.

```
You can now load the model via spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/shahid/Documents/simple_nlp/NlpFactory/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from NlpFactory.NlpFactory import NLPFactory
  File "/home/shahid/Documents/simple_nlp/NlpFactory/NlpFactory.py", line 28, in <module>
    nlp = spacy.load(os.path.abspath('en_core_web_md'))
  File "/home/shahid/anaconda3/envs/eda_test_7/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 30, in load
    return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
  File "/home/shahid/anaconda3/envs/eda_test_7/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 175, in load_model
    raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
OSError: [E050] Can't find model '/home/shahid/Documents/simple_nlp/en_core_web_md'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

I have looked at this question about vendoring but it is not recommended so I am not going to adopt it. [Package spacy model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57773454/package-spacy-model)

Comment: These sorts of issues are almost always something to do with an incorrect interpreter.

Can you verify they're the same by checking the output of `os.system("which python")` and ensuring that it matches with the output of `print(sys.executable)`?

If they aren't the same, try replacing `"python -m spacy..."` with `"{} -m spacy...".format(sys.executable)`

Comment: they are same in my case
/home/shahid/anaconda3/envs/eda_test_7/bin/python

Comment: Are you certain the model installer completed without error? Also, is it possible there's a permissions issue with the model file?