# How to check for modules that need to be installed manually with setuptools (or comparable tools)?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I'm using `setuptools` to install a Python module that I'm working on. In addition to `numpy`, `scipy`, ..., whose presence I can assure with `install_requires = [...]`, my module also depends on a Python module - let's call it `specialmodule` - that is a Python interface to a program that is neither an egg, nor a single .py-file or a VCS repo (so [Dependencies that aren’t in PyPI](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi) is not applicable). The program is written in C++ and has a Python interface, and can either be built from source after cloning from git, or obtained as a tar archive.

Is there a way to use `setuptools` to check the existence of this module (which is in `PYTHONPATH`), and if it can not be found, display some message to the user that the module is missing (and if possible, also some instructions on how to get it)?

**Edit:** Also, if there is a more elegant way to do this with a different approach than with `setuptools`, I'd be glad to hear! But I would really like to check directly on installation, not during runtime of my module.

Comment: A quick look through the documentation found [this](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi) - did you look at it already?

Comment: @DavidZ Yes I already saw that, but unfortunately, `specialmodule` is a Python interface to a program that is neither an egg, nor a single .py-file or a VCS repo. The program is written in C++ and has a Python interface, and can either be built from source after cloning from git, or obtained as a tar archive.

Comment: That's fairly essential information to include in the question. (Actually a link to the actual module in question wouldn't hurt.)

Comment: What prevent you from creating an egg for `specialmodule` ?

Comment: @Cyrbil This is not in my field of action, I would not want to have to provide new eggs for every new version of the program in addition to my software. I think I would rather try to `import specialmodule` during installtion, and give suggestions on what to do in case this fails.

Comment: I was able to solve the task using a custom install command, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915469/python-setuptools-install-requires-is-ignored-when-overriding-cmdclass).