# Python package with pywin32 or pypiwin32 dependency

Tags: python, setuptools, pywin32

I'm building a python package which requires pywin32.

Adding pywin32 as a dependency doesn't work seamlessly, since it has a postinstall script which the user must run themselves.

Adding pypiwin32 as a dependency doesn't work because my package won't play nice with other packages which do require pywin32

I tried requiring both, but it turns out pywin32 and pypiwin32 can't coexist on the same python installation

Is there a way of specifying either pywin32 or pypiwin32 as a dependency? Or some other solution?

Comment: [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764978/using-win32com-with-multithreading) and never forget "The application will not react like DLL", need be `shared` and `registered` otherwise will not work or work a partition !

Comment: Thank you, I read it but didn't really understand how passing com objects across threads relates to this scenario

Comment: `Adding pywin32 as a dependency` resource access will not work ! You can't add your dependencies as `system required/registered` module. Got 2 way : 1-use a `dll` as module,2- Use minimal-common libraries(not full library)

Comment: You can used  method on the link If you are the manager of all computers. I fixed this problem with "Compiled execute for every machine", different machines different errors ! Waste a lot time. Maybe not good idea but "install python+pythonwin to every machine" your application(.exe) will be work without any error.

Comment: _pywin32_ and _pypiwin32_ is one and the same package, only the shipping form differs.

Comment: @CristiFati I am aware, but they are registered as different packages, meaning a package with pywin32 in its dependencies won't accept pypiwin32

Comment: _pywin32_ comes as an executable, while _pypiwin32_ (is the newer form that) comes as a _.whl_ (which can be a dependency for other packages). How can a package have a _pywin32_ as a dependency (since it doesn't exist)? Something doesn't seem to be right here.

Answer (score 1):

The [adding pip install pywin32 as a post-install script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288711/post-install-script-with-python-setuptools) works, but removes the install_requires command from setup. To fix this, [add do_egg_install(self) rather than run in the classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915469/python-setuptools-install-requires-is-ignored-when-overriding-cmdclass)

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.develop import develop as _develop
from setuptools.command.install import install as _install
from subprocess import check_call

# PostDevelopCommand
class develop(_develop):
    """Post-installation for development mode."""
    def run(self):
        check_call("pip install pywin32")
        develop.do_egg_install(self)

# PostInstallCommand
class install(_install):
    """Post-installation for installation mode."""
    def run(self):
        check_call("pip install pywin32")
        develop.do_egg_install(self)
```

and insert cmdclass argument to setup() function in setup.py:

```
 setup(
     ...

    cmdclass={
        'develop': develop,
        'install': install,
    },

    ...
)
```