# What is wrong with my custom install script in Python setup.py?

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, setuptools

Hi I am new to Python programming. I have written the following `setup.py` script to install the dependencies by customizing the install. But, the python packages are not installed in my virtual environment. Please help me.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools.command.install import install


class CustomInstallCommand(install):
    """Customized setuptools install command - prints a friendly greeting."""

    def run(self):
        print("I am trying to install ...")
        install.run(self)

# dependencies = ['configparser == 4.0.2', 'colorama == 0.4.3', 'xlsxwriter == 1.2.7']


setup(cmdclass={
        'install': CustomInstallCommand,
        },
    name='Testing',
      version='0.1',
      author='DD Mishra',
      description='PDE Integration testing',
      packages=find_packages(),
      install_requires=['configparser == 4.0.2', 'colorama == 0.4.3', 'xlsxwriter == 1.2.7']
      )
```

If I remove the following line from `setup()` function, it works fine.

```
cmdclass={
        'install': CustomInstallCommand,
        },
```

What may be the issue ? Please help me to resolve. I am trying to achieve maven or gradle type feature which we in Java, in Python.

Comment: What exactly works and doesn't work with and without `cmdclass`? Any error? Saw https://stackoverflow.com/q/21915469/7976758? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+cmdclass+install

Comment: @phd, Sir, Excellent, it worked. Thank you very much. You can answer so that I can accept the answer.